# How to expand a 2d matrix to 3d by replacing the scalar with a vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array like this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0 ,0]])
```

with shape `(2,3)`. Indexing at some point would give a scalar, for example `a[0,0] = 1` How can I turn this into a 3d array by replacing the scalar with a vector of length x filled with the initial scalar? For example say x = 5, I would want `a[0,0] = [1,1,1,1,1]` , `a[0,1] = [0,0,0,0,0]`, ... and the shape of `a` to be `(2,3,x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `a.repeat()` and then `reshape`:

```
x = 5
new_a = a.repeat(x).reshape(*a.shape, -1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_a
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])

>>> new_a[0, 0]
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

>>> new_a[0, 1]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Alternatively: `np.tile(a[..., None], 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0 ,0]])
x = 5

np.einsum('ij,k', a, np.ones(x, dtype=a.dtype))
```

Output

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```